# ng-model binding with item id

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**case:**

I need to bind an input field with a specific hidden field, and I want to refer to it by ID because I have many of those input vs hidden input in my page.

Something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item.name-{{item.ID}}" >

 <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{item.name-{{item.ID}}}}" >
```

Item will be an object, where it looks like this:

```
$scope.item = {ID: '11111', name:'itemname'}
```

The item name can be edited through this input field where we will insert the name and it will be binded to a hidden field to be submitted with the form.

Thank you.

Comment: could you share your controller/link function code ? from this code its hard to know what `item.name-{{item.ID}}` is ?

Comment: @jad item will be an object , where it looks like this : $scope.item = {ID: '11111', name:'itemname'} , ,,, the item name can be edited through this input field where we will insert the name and it will be binded to a hidden field to be submitted with the form .

Comment: what kind of object ? can you add that in question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/ap53mubd/ see this fiddle, is it what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another object for storing key-value pairs with data from your dynamic inputs. I think this approach is more cleaner.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="itemsValues[firstItem.name + '-' + firstItem.ID]" >
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="{{itemsValues[firstItem.name + '-' + firstItem.ID]}}" >
```

[Demo on plunker (with three inputs)](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z7qdif?p=preview).